# ObservableArray to Select Option in KnockOut JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to turn array to select option via knockout js, I know 3 methods for this case, but none of these work perfectly with what I really want, what I want is:

1. Set default option `Choose an option`
2. get selected value
3. set `attr` for options

Each method has own issue, but last method has default option and can get selected value, but can't set `attr`, any idea?

**Method 1:**

Error:

> Uncaught Error: The binding 'value' cannot be used with virtual
>   elements

Status: not working

```js
function myfunc() {
  var self = this;
  self.estimate = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
  
  var obj = [{
      method_title: "blah blah",
      price: "1000"
    },
    {
      method_title: "blah blah 2",
      price: "2000"
    }
  ];
  self.estimate(obj);
  self.selectedValue.subscribe(function(value) {
    alert(value);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new myfunc());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select id="method">
  <option value="0">Choose an option</option>
  <!-- ko foreach: estimate, value: selectedValue -->
  <option data-bind="text: method_title,
                       attr: { 'data-price': price, 'value': method_title },
                       text: method_title"></option>
  <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

**Method 2:**

Status: working but I could not add default option, it looped everytime.

```js
function myfunc() {
  var self = this;
  self.estimate = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
  
  var obj = [{
      method_title: "blah blah",
      price: "1000"
    },
    {
      method_title: "blah blah 2",
      price: "2000"
    }
  ];
  self.estimate(obj);
  self.selectedValue.subscribe(function(value) {
    alert(value);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new myfunc());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <select id="method" data-bind="foreach: estimate,value: selectedValue">
        <option value="0">Choose an option</option>
            <option data-bind="text: method_title,attr: {'data-price':  price, value: method_title}"></option>
        </select>
```

**Method 3:**

Status: working but I could not set `attr`

```js
function myfunc() {
  var self = this;
  self.estimate = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();

  var obj = [{
      method_title: "blah blah",
      price: "1000"
    },
    {
      method_title: "blah blah 2",
      price: "2000"
    }
  ];
  self.estimate(obj);
  self.selectedValue.subscribe(function(value) {
    alert(value);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new myfunc());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="method" data-bind="value: selectedValue,options: estimate,
                       optionsText: 'method_title',
                       optionsValue: 'method_title',
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose an option'"></select>
```

Comment: Be aware that browsers might strip comments from inside `select` elements before Knockout ever sees those. IE 8 for example does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method had the most promise and so I have corrected that. You don't need to use the `value` binding in the `foreach` loop. It has to be used in the `<select>`, and it works fine.

```js
function myfunc() {
  var self = this;
  self.estimate = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
  
  var obj = [{
      method_title: "blah blah",
      price: "1000"
    },
    {
      method_title: "blah blah 2",
      price: "2000"
    }
  ];
  self.estimate(obj);
  self.selectedValue.subscribe(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new myfunc());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select id="method" data-bind="value: selectedValue">
  <option value="0">Choose an option</option>
  <!-- ko foreach: estimate -->
  <option data-bind="text: method_title,
                       attr: { 'data-price': price, 'value': method_title }"></option>
  <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a little bit modification with your 3rd method.

From knockout official documentation [Knockout: The "options" binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) you can use optionsAfterRender Parameter. I have modified your code. See if it helps

```js
function myfunc() {
  var self = this;
  self.estimate = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedValue = ko.observable();

  var obj = [{
      method_title: "blah blah",
      price: "1000",
      href: "href 1",
      title: "go to href 1"
    },
    {
      method_title: "blah blah 2",
      price: "2000",
      href: "href 2",
      title: "go to href 2"
    }
  ];
  self.setOptionAttr = function(option, item) {           
       if(item)
       {
       ko.applyBindingsToNode(option, {attr: {href:item.href,title:item.title}}, item);
       }            
    }
  self.estimate(obj);
  self.selectedValue.subscribe(function(value) {
    alert(value);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new myfunc());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<select id="method" data-bind="value: selectedValue,options: estimate,
                       optionsText: 'method_title',
                       optionsValue: 'method_title',
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose an option',
                       optionsAfterRender: setOptionAttr"></select>
```